# Special Characters RSS Feeds

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm using

```
simplexml_load_file($url)
```

to read an rss feed.

Sample: 'If you start with nothing and end up with nothing, there’s nothing lost.

When rss item contains single quote it will display as **â€™**, when I output to screen.

How will be a good way to sanitize rss feed input?

Comment: This is an encoding issue. What encoding is $url and what encoding is your output?

Comment: the rss feed is utf-8. I'm not specifying an encoding on my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the above problem by sending this header first with output:

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```